# Python Curses Flush newest x stdin

Tags: python, stdin, flush, curses

I am developing a small python script which uses curses to read the stdin of the terminal. As the users holds down the key the `movement_smallstep` should be incremented for a faster general movement after x 'repeats'. This function gets called every keypress. As the UI change of the movement and the function aren't in synch the user generally 'overshoots' the target and I therefore want to flush some of the curses's stdin.

```
def movement_manager(step,repeats,key):
    global old_key #remembering the n-1 pressed key of stdin
    global input_repeats #remembering how often the key was pressed
    global movement_smallstep #movement for ui change
    if key != old_key:
        input_key = key
        input_repeats = 0
        movement_smallstep = 1
    if (input_repeats > repeats):
        movement_smallstep+=1
        #Flush the newest x stdin inputs of the queue here
    input_repeats+=1
    return movement_smallstep
```

So for example the user presses the key 'A' 23 times.

```
Movement(repeats 0-10)=1    Stdin= Unflushed
Movement(repeats 10-20)=2   Stdin= flush oldest userinput
Movement(repeats 10-20)=3   Stdin= flush oldest 2 userinputs
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`flushinp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.flushinp) function to discard input, or [`typeahead`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.typeahead) to discard output (when that falls behind).  For the latter, the file descriptor would be **`1`** (for the standard output).